# Keep trailing zeros on Timestamp SELECT

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, date-format

This is the issue:
I am reading rows with a timestamp column from a table and I need to make sure that the database returns the timestamp with a fixed width. But I am encountering instances where the PostgreSQL database returns the timestamp without the trailing zeros.

The table I am working on contains `UUID`, `Varchar`, `Smallint` and `Timestamp`.
I understand that I can use "to_char" as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401221/make-postgresql-timestamps-display-milliseconds-even-if-zero), but what I am really looking for is a way tell PostgreSQL to always return the Timestamp in a given format, regardless of zeros.

Here is an example of the output from the `Timestamp` column I get, which contains a trimmed Timestamp:

```
"2014-09-26 17:17:45.999"
"2014-11-26 17:17:46"
"2015-03-26 17:17:46.001"
"2015-04-26 17:17:46.002"
"2015-05-26 17:17:46.003"
```

This will naturally cause a problem for me since the function that is reading from the database expects to get a timestamp in a given format.

Is there a way to make the PostgreSQL always return a timestamp with a fixed width on `SELECT * FROM [table]` queries?

Below you see how the fields are created:

```
"created_UTC" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'),
"last_modified_UTC" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

Comment: Try the Postgres documentation on [date formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: Doesn't the answer in the linked question say it all?: **"Doesn't look like there is any such option."**

Comment: _the function that is reading from the database expects to get a timestamp in a given format_ To me this means that the given function expect these to be __text__ parameters, not timestamps.  It would otherwise be content with the timestamp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth, I managed to figure what was actually going on and how to fix it.

> the function that is reading from the database expects to get a timestamp in a given format To me this means that the given function expect these to be text parameters, not timestamps. It would otherwise be content with the timestamp... –  dezso Jan 27 at 20:22

This was helpful because it lead to me to understand that if you ask the JDBC for PostgreSQL to return a Timestamp as String, it will automatically trim the zeroes at the end.

Example:

```
ResultSet rs = {get rows from database}
rs.getString(TIMESTAMP_COLUMN);
```

will return a potentially shortened (trimmed) string with the last zeroes removed.

While:

```
ResultSet rs = {get rows from database}
rs.getTimestamp(TIMESTAMP_COLUMN);
```

will actually return a Java Timestamp object, with no trimming issues.

This is unexpected behavior and I'm not sure what the reasoning behind trimming strings can be, but I have at least figured out where the issue is and how to fix it.

Many thanks for the assistance. Huzzah!

Comment: There is no "trimming" involved. Text representation is derived from the internal numerical value according to formatting instructions. I wouldn't trust JDBC to do the right thing automatically. That can depend on locale and time zone settings of the session. To get a custom text representation, use `to_char()` as mentioned in the referenced answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to set the Timestamp column to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`. This would set the column to return the time to the three digit precision you are looking for.

Comment: I added the field creation text for clarification.